# Composer: Multiple packages in SVN repository

Tags: svn, composer-php, satis

I'm working on a project (let's call it Application A) which contains multiple modules (like module A and module B). Those modules are used in this project, but I also want those modules to be exposed to other projects (so Application B can use module A, for example). The main project, Application A, is located in a SVN repository with the following (simplified) directory structure:

```
trunk/
    module/
      moduleA/
       src/ 
       composer.json -> Composer file for module A
      moduleB/
        src/
        composer.json -> Composer file for module B
    composer.json -> Composer file for Application A
```

I'm using composer to manage dependencies. I want to use Satis to create a private repository which contains my module packages (module A, module B etc). I added my SVN repository as a repository to my Satis configuration file:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "svn://xxx/ApplicationA/"
    }
]
```

But this doesn't generate the `packages.json` like I want. The only package in the `packages.json` file is Application A, but I want all the module packages to be in this file, so I would like Composer/Satis to scan for **all** `composer.json` files (also in subfolders).

I can add a specific repository for each package, but I don't want that, because in that case I need to edit my Satis configuration for each new module.

I tried a lot of things like setting `trunk-path`, `branches-path`, `tags-path` and `package-path` in my Satis configuration file, but I can get this working.

In short: I'm trying to get Composer/Satis working with multiple packages in 1 SVN repository. Does anyone know how to achieve this? Or maybe there's a better approach to solve my 'problem'?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I dont think satis supports this - the way I got round it was to add a build step using [rake](http://rake.rubyforge.org/), although you could use [phing](http://www.phing.info/) or even a shell script, which looped through all the paths in our svn repo and generated a config.json from that. This does mean you have to re run the buildstep every time you add a svn repo, but you will need to have the satis creation running as a cronjob / post commit hook anyway.

If a build script isn't possible, you might have to look at getting [packagist](http://packagist.org/) setup, which would require you to add packages manually, but doesnt require generating a `config.json` entry for every repository.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, due to some other projects this issue had a lower priority. Thanks for your answer @timmow. I already looked at packagist and I guess using it is the best option. I'll give it a try!